# How can I retrieve a particular field from JSON object using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, json, promise, javascript-objects, aws-sdk-nodejs

This is the format of the JSON object I am trying to retrieve field TEMP from.

```
[
    [
        {
            "DEVICE_ID": "357807272",
            "TEMP": 20.439
        }
     ]
 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript filter to retrieve objects, please find below code snippet:

```
var heroes = [
{name: 'Batman', franchise: 'DC'},
{name: 'Ironman', franchise: 'Marvel'},
{name: 'Thor', franchise: 'Marvel'},
{name: 'Superman', franchise: 'DC'}
];

var marvelHeroes =  heroes.filter(function(hero) {
 return hero.franchise == 'Marvel';
});
console.log(marvelHeroes);
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the OPs structure at all.

Comment: @Bergi this was a suggestive approach